# Does the JVM's Garbage Collector clean the entire JVM HotSpot memory (C-Heap, Java Heap and Permanent Generation space) or just Java Heap?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap

I know that the JVM has some **JVM HotSpot memory** which is further divided into three areas:

- **Java Heap**
- **Permanent Generation Space**
- **Native Heap (C-Heap)**

I know that Java has automatic garbage collection mechanism for *Heap* *Memory*.

So, I want to confirm that in my last statement *Heap* refers to both *Java Heap* and *Native Heap (C-Heap)* or just *Java Heap*.

Also, what about *Permanent Generation Space*? Is it also considered as some kind of Heap or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GC will collect both the Java Heap and the permgen, but not the native heap. The native heap is manually managed by whatever C code owns it. The permgen, on the other hand, is managed by the JVM garbage collector (though not necessarily as efficiently as the rest of the heap, as certain GC algorithms will only compact the permgen when absolutely necessary).

Comment: Does the hot spot compiler even use a heap? All the memory required by an Object should be allocated on the Java Heap. All the native code should need is some stack space for immediate processing. Perhaps someone could clarify.

Comment: @JamesAnderson the "native heap" is the heap used by native code. For example, when you make certain library IO calls it will call native C code, which will then malloc and free memory to do its business.

Comment: but surly these calls are made by the main compiled and delivered JVM code. Why should the code generated by the JIT compiler need any heap space?

Comment: @JamesAnderson I'm not talking about code compiled by the JIT. You know how Java can call out to native code, right? Well that native code obviously can't allocate Java objects, so it has to malloc its own memory.

Comment: I agree! but the OP was asking about the Hot Spot compiler (among other things!).

Comment: @JamesAnderson ah, I see what you mean. Mav3n, were you just talking about the HotSpot compiler, or all memory owned by the JVM?

Comment: @mav3n through the [Java Native Interface](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). Is that what you were wondering?

Comment: @raptortech97 I didn't knew JVM also own memory other than HotSpot Memory... Can you refer some article or explain what memory other than this HotSpot Memory JVM owns. Also can you also explain how Java calls out native code?

Comment: @raptortech97 I was not specifically referring to JNI... I was asking in general..